# Progress bar is not showing on phone after clicking on notification status bar

Tags: android, download, android-notifications, android-progressbar

When i am downloading the file from the server its downloading well,in the notification status bar its showing the progress bar but when i selecting from the notification status bar it will open that application but at that time progress bar is not showing in the phone but its working fine on emulator.Please help me out......

### Thanks..

```
  public class FileDownloadTestActivity extends Activity {

private static String url = "http://www.xxxxx.in/build/android/android/xyz.apk";
public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0;
private Button startBtn;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    startBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.download);
    Boolean boolean1=true;
    if(boolean1){
    startBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            new DownloadFileAsync().execute(url);
        }
    });
    boolean1=false;
    }
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS:
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading file..");
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressDialog.show();
        return mProgressDialog;
    default:
        return null;
    }

}

class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    NotificationManager notificationManager;
    Notification notification2;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() { 
        super.onPreExecute();
         notification2 = new Notification(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download, "downloading..." , System.currentTimeMillis());

         Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FileDownloadTestActivity.class);
           intent .setAction("android.intent.action.MAIN");
           intent .addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");      
            final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);

            notification2 = new Notification(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download, "downloading..." , System.currentTimeMillis());
            notification2.flags = notification2.flags | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
            notification2.contentView = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification_layout);
            notification2.contentIntent = pendingIntent;
            notification2.contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.status_icon,R.drawable.junow );
            notification2.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.status_progress, 100, 1, false);
            getApplicationContext();
            notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
        int count;

        try {

            URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
            URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
            conexion.connect();

            int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/xyz.apk");

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;

                long var=(int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile);
                publishProgress("" +var);
                output.write(data, 0, count);
                notificationManager.notify(1, notification2);   
            }
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
         mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
         notification2.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.status_progress, 100,Integer.parseInt(progress[0]), false);
         notification2.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.percent,"Downloading in progress  "+progress[0]+" %");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
        dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
        notificationManager.cancel(1); 
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/xyz.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        startActivity(intent); 


    }
}
```

}